# Mocking exception in unit test (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

```
Class Chains()
    chains = [local.feeder.ILUT, local.reacher.OHUT]
    def get_chain():
        if photon_chain:
            for i in chains:
                try:
                    return i.get_value(photon_chain)
                except Exception as exc:
                    _log.error(exc)
                    raise Exception(exc)
```

I have not included the **init** part of the class. It accepts several params including photon_chain of the specified method.

My unit test to cover the "exception" part looks like this:

```
def test_get_chain():
    chain_1 = Chains(photon_chain='chainvalue')
    with mock.patch('get_value', side_effect=Exception):
        chain_1.get_chain()
```

Unit test is not passing and the error is occurring at the catching part as shown below.

```
> raise Exception(exc)
E Exception
```

I am new to mocking and I just know that this mock.patch raises exception when it is specified as a side_effect.

Comment: Where does the `chains` variable come from in the for loop?

Comment: I have a list "chains" defined in the class.

Comment: Can you provide it in your post?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Added in the post

Comment: @slideshowp2 It contains references to other classes

Comment: Can you adapt the code to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Right now the code has some syntax errors, and it is also not clear what you actually want to test.